# panda read xlsx file datetime issue

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am attempting to read an excel file and parse the contents into a Python dictionary.

```
from pandas import *

xls = ExcelFile('vavs.xlsx')
data = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0])
print(data.to_dict())
```

The problem that I am running into is a format of one of the cells inside the excel file. This column represents a network & address information and Excel thinks this is a time, like `11:01 AM`

[image]

What I am attempting to use this for I need the formatting `11:01` to be as is.. When I print the dictionary in Python it comes thru with an unwanted `datetime.time` and I only want a string `11:01`

```
 'trunkAddress': {0: datetime.time(11, 1),
  1: datetime.time(11, 2),
  2: datetime.time(11, 3),
  3: datetime.time(11, 4),
  4: datetime.time(11, 5),
  5: datetime.time(11, 6),
  6: datetime.time(11, 16),
  7: datetime.time(11, 17),
  8: datetime.time(11, 18)},
```

Is there a way around this? Like converting the Excel file to a csv and then reading the data into Python? This is a small excel file for testing purposes, for whatever its worth I have the file in my git account [here](https://github.com/bbartling/Data/blob/master/vavs.xlsx).

Thanks for tips

Comment: You can specify the data type of each column you read, something like `dtype={'trunkAdress':'str'}` should do

Comment: Could you post an answer how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
df = pd.read_excel('your_table.xlsx', dtype={'trunkAdress':str}
```

Comment: I ended up using a `data = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0],dtype={'trunkAdress':str})`